# Issue in adding dynamic cell in table view?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

Please have a look on my code which i am using to add dynamic cells in my table view add run time. At did select of my table view i have called this method.

```
 - (void) allServersFound 
{
    // called from delegate when bonjourservices has listings of machines:
    NSArray *newPosts = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"A", nil]; // NSArray of machine names;

NSMutableArray *tempArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects: @"A",@"B",@"C",@"D", nil];

int i = 0;
for (NSArray *count in newPosts)
{
    [tempArray addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i++ inSection:0]];
}

[[self tblHome] beginUpdates];
[[self tblHome] insertRowsAtIndexPaths:tempArray withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
[[self tblHome] endUpdates];

[tempArray release];
}
```

But this give me following Exception at run time:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSIndexPath _fastCStringContents:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4e0e130

Answer (score 1):

First you initialize your **tempArray** with strings like this:

```
NSMutableArray *tempArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects: @"A",@"B",@"C",@"D", nil];
```

Then you add indexPaths like this:

```
[tempArray addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i++ inSection:0]];
```

so the array you pass to the *insertRowsAtIndexPaths* method contains both strings and indexPaths objects. I think this is the reason of the exception.

Answer (score 1):

As others noted, your `tempArray` contains a mixture of `NSString` and `NSIndexPath` objects. This is the most obvious thing that you need to address before you do anything else. You can use `[NSMutableArray array]` class method for that (it's autoreleased, so you'll need to remove the call to `[tempArray release]` at the end of your method).

A less obvious thing is that the *model* of your UITableView *must* be updated before you call `insertRowsAtIndexPaths`, otherwise you would get another exception in a much less obvious place.

Answer (score 0):

Your `tmparray` contains `NSString` values as well as the `IndexPath`s, try removing the `NSString`s first.
Try replacing the line

```
NSMutableArray *tempArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects: @"A",@"B",@"C",@"D", nil];
```

with the line

```
NSMutableArray *tempArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:nil];
```